# CSS Input field design

Tags: html, css, input, responsive-design, materialize

I need to make a input box like the image below.

[image]

I'm using materialize and CSS.

Comment: You need to ask an actual question for your question to be on topic here. Are you having trouble positioning the "username" portion? The circular X button? The rounded border? The color? The padding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use fieldset in your form element.

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <label for="username">Username</label>
  </legend>
  <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
</fieldset>
```

After that, you can try to edit your styling in your css. Probably to take out the border of the input and change the width of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Basic demonstration using `:before`.

```css
input {
  border: transparent;
  text-align: left;
}

input::placeholder {
  text-align: center;
}

input:focus {
  outline: transparent;
}

.line {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 10px 0px 5px 0px;
}

.line:before {
  content: "username";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
<input type="text" placeholder="me@example.com">
</div>
```